# Potentially dangerous Request.Form value detected (even if the value doesn't exist)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So, as the title say, I am running into this particular error randomly. When I select a particular search criteria, and then use paging events to move to next page, system throws this error.

Funny thing is, not only the search criteria has to specific, but the value doesn't exist. According to .Net, this is the error

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (objListOfMR^MRHD_MR_Description~7="...ion ASMSD <asmsd@autoshell.com...").
```

Where MR description is the text field taken from database. So, I checked the database, and the actual value is

```
Alarm P on PSM unit
```

No other field has that line `<asmsd@autoshell.com` anywhere. All records on Page 2 or further of the search result, show this error.

I tried the same thing on the test database (copy of live database), and that worked wonderfully. without any errors.

So, first thing I want to do is, know where is this line coming from. And why is it not coming for test database.

I know how to do a quick hack to fix this, but that's not what I want to try right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: It's obviously coming from somewhere. If its not in your Db then your client-side form code or whatever. We can't help you look through your source code for a particular bit of text though.

Comment: Already did. It is no where in database, or full solution. :/

Comment: Ok, so tried the "ValidateRequest=false" in the page. Doesn't work. Same error for all records. Also, if this value was in source code or database, it should cause same problem always. But, it does so when I search for record using that specific criteria. If I search the record number directly, no error at all.

Comment: It could be in your cookies. Try an "Incognito" mode ...

Comment: Tried incognito. Tried deleting browser cache and history. No luck yet.